# How to get python output and print with php

Tags: python, php, localhost, recommendation-engine, shell-exec

This my python file hi.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

data = pd.read_csv("C:/xampp/htdocs/product.csv")
data['content'] = data['Brand']+' '+data['Title']+' '+data['Product Type']+' 
'+data['Gender']+' '+data['Price'].astype(str)+' '+data['MRP'].astype(str)+' 
'+data['Rating'].astype(str)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=1000)
product_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['content'].values)


from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
similarity = cosine_similarity(product_vectors)

def recommend(content):

 # find  index from dataset
 content_index = data[data['Title'] == content].index[0]

 # finding cosine similarities 
 distances = similarity[content_index]

# sorting cosine similarities
 my_list = sorted(list(enumerate(distances)),reverse=True,key=lambda x:x[1])[1:10]
 dh=[]
#return my_list
 for i in my_list:
    #print(data.iloc[i[0]].Title)
    dh.append(data.loc[i[0]].Title)
     #return dh
print(recommend('Adidas Men Running Shoes'))
```

I need the list of recommended products to be printed in php localhost.
This is my php file:

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('py hi.py');
echo $output;
?>
```

However when I'm running the php file I'm getting output in VSCode but nothing is printed when I run on localhost.

What might be the problem please help me.

Comment: use relative paths, it is possible when you are using scripts from local host the path is changed, try to print current directory in shell_exec it will let you know better about current directory, also dump actual error message so that it will help us a lot to figure out what went wrong behind the scene.

Comment: I am getting no error just blank screen when running on localhost

Comment: then try the system function instead of shell_exec

Comment: Look we first have to find out error modify your command as "py hi.py 2>&1" i am preety much sure thiis will display your error and you will find hint to proceed further

Comment: I tried system ,passthru and ecsapeshellcmd but it's still no output when running on localhost.

Comment: try my modified command in shell_exec

Comment: I'm getting this error using hi.py 2>&1 : Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\xampp\htdocs\prac.py", line 2, in import pandas as pd File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 16, in raise ImportError( ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies: dateutil: No module named 'dateutil' dateutil: No module named 'dateutil'

Comment: its the module error dateutil try to install it, pip install python-dateutil

Comment: did this remedy worked?

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: check if your same python version is being called in shell_exec . what python version you are using outside of localhost . . i mean when you run that python file without php localhost

Comment: I'm using Windows

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\xampp\htdocs\hi.py", line 2, in import pandas as pd File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 22, in from pandas.compat import ( File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py", line 15, in from pandas.compat.numpy import ( File  "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\dateutil\tz\tz.py", line 19, in import six ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

Comment: No this time error is not same its different  . looks like your php is running under different user so its not finding python modules, this time six module is missing, if you have requirements file simply install all modules or install one by one .

Comment: pip3 install six
this will install the module

Comment: Ok so I uninstalled and reinstalled the module six and the code worked thanks for your help.

Comment: For the help of others i am posting the answer explaining the issue accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your PHP code e.g. it's executing the command but it is only returning the standard output stream to you, that's the reason on error you are getting the blank screen because the `shell_exec` is not redirecting the error stream, to do so modify your code as shown below

```
<?php
$output=shell_exec('py hi.py 2>&1');
echo $output;
?>
```

Once the error is shown you will be able to solve your issue.